# How to print words ending in "rry" from a text file?

Tags: regex, text, grep

I have text file that contains thousands of words. For example:

```
carry
car
house
notebook
handbook
party
hurry
```

I want to print just words that ends on "rry". My output should include:

```
carry
hurry
```

Is this possible with grep or some other bash program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Fixed Strings

If you're confident that your data won't include the pattern "rry" inside a word, it is faster to search for fixed strings than regular expressions. For example, the following commands are equivalent with GNU grep:

```
$ grep --fixed-strings rry /tmp/foo
$ fgrep rry /tmp/bar
```

### Use Word Boundaries

As an alternative, if you only want to match words that *end* in "rry" you need to check for a word boundary or end-of-line marker. For example:

```
$ grep 'rry\b' /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep rry$ sample.txt`

Sample.txt:

```
  1 carry
  2 car
  3 house
  4 notebook
  5 handbook
  6 party
  7 hurry
  8 rryasdf
```

Prints

```
carry
hurry
```